# Spring Data Elasticsearch: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an error with Spring Data Rest and Spring Elasticsearch in a Spring Boot Application.

These are the components of my simple project:

- pom.xml

  ```
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>test</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring.elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>

      <name>Template per webapp</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8181</url>

      <properties>
          <spring.boot.version>1.4.0.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
          <com.h2database.version>1.4.192</com.h2database.version>
          <com.sun.jna.version>3.0.9</com.sun.jna.version>        
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot</artifactId>
              <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
              <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
              <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
              <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
              <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
              <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
              <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
              <version>${com.h2database.version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>com.sun.jna</groupId>
              <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
              <version>${com.sun.jna.version}</version>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
              <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
              <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-smile</artifactId>
              <version>2.8.1</version>
          </dependency>

          <dependency>
              <groupId>junit</groupId>
              <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
              <version>3.8.1</version>
              <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <build>
          <plugins>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>3.0</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <source>1.8</source>
                      <target>1.8</target>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
              <plugin>
                  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                  <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                  <version>2.7</version>
                  <configuration>
                      <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                      <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                      <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                      <additionalBuildcommands>
                          <buildCommand>
                              <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                          </buildCommand>
                      </additionalBuildcommands>
                      <additionalProjectnatures>
                          <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                      </additionalProjectnatures>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </build>
  </project>
  ```
- Spring Boot Application

  ```
  @SpringBootApplication
  public class Application {

      public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
      }

  }
  ```
- Java configuration

  ```
  @Configuration
  @EnableJpaRepositories
  @EnableElasticsearchRepositories
  public class ElasticSearchConfig {

  }
  ```
- Spring data entity

  ```
  @Entity
  @Document(indexName = "computerindex")
  public class Computer {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
      private long id;
      @Field private String name; 
      @Field private String brand;

      /** getters and setters **/

  }
  ```
- Repository

  ```
  @RepositoryRestResource(exported=true)
  public interface ComputerRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Computer, String>{

  }
  ```

The application starts with success without any errors.

This is the structure of the autogenerated indexes:

```
data
    elasticsearch
        nodes
            0
                _state
                indices
                    computerindex
                        _state
                        0
                            _state
                            index
                            translog
                        1
                        2
                        3
                        4
                node.lock
```

When I go to the url `http://localhost:8080/` I have this expected response:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "computers" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/computers{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "profile" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to make an http POST to the url `http://localhost:8080/computers` with `content-type "application/json"` and with this input:

```
{
  "name" : "pc",
  "brand" : "brand"
}
```

I have this error:

```
2016-08-04 09:34:41.245 ERROR 6884 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.d.r.w.RepositoryRestExceptionHandler : java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.SimpleElasticsearchRepository.stringIdRepresentation(SimpleElasticsearchRepository.java:28) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.createIndexQuery(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:255) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.repository.support.AbstractElasticsearchRepository.save(AbstractElasticsearchRepository.java:142) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:503) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:488) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:460) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy92.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.support.CrudRepositoryInvoker.invokeSave(CrudRepositoryInvoker.java:100) ~[spring-data-commons-1.12.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory$UnwrappingRepositoryInvoker.invokeSave(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:222) ~[spring-data-rest-core-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.createAndReturn(RepositoryEntityController.java:501) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.RepositoryEntityController.postCollectionResource(RepositoryEntityController.java:275) ~[spring-data-rest-webmvc-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:87) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.2.RELEASE.jar:4.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.4.jar:8.5.4]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_65]
```

I suppose that the error involves the `@Id` field, because it's the only field with a `long` type.

What's the reason of this error? How can I do to solve it?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I don't exclude that it can be a bug.

This is the "`stringIdRepresentation`" method declaration in the `AbstracElasticsearchRepository`:

```
protected abstract String stringIdRepresentation(ID id);
```

And this is the implementation in the class `SimpleElasticsearchRepository`:

```
@Override
protected String stringIdRepresentation(String id) {
    return id;
}
```

With this implementation, the class expects a String as id by default, without making any conversion before.

Answer (score 2):

I have partially solved replacing the `long id` with a `String id`, in this way:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator="system-uuid")
@GenericGenerator(name="system-uuid", strategy = "uuid")
private String id;
```

The exception was caused exactly by the type of the `@Id` field.

Using a String as the `@Id`, there is no more any error.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to reply to an old question but i thought i might ship in to avoid solving this problem by the work around of using different data type.
the only problem is that you have specified the primary key type as String in your ElasticSearchRepository class
you wrote it as

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported=true)
public interface ComputerRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Computer, 
String>{
}
```

it should be

```
@RepositoryRestResource(exported=true)
public interface ComputerRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Computer, Long>{

}
```

since your primary key is long